# Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack

Tags: servlets, java-11, tomcat9

I have exiting Spring web application which runs fine with Java 8 and tomcat 9.

We have upgraded to Java 11 now, application sems to be working fine in local environment, but fails in production. There was no code change required, and app was build and ran properly in local environment.

I added below to my runtime args, and app worked fine.

```
-Xverify:none
```

But removing this arg, app fails with below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:731)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1185)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1933)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1095)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:477)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:437)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:934)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/availmentsin]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
                ... 37 more
        Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
```

Exception Details:
Location:
(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;)V @712: invokevirtual
Reason:
Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Exception'
Current Frame:
bci: @712
flags: { }

locals: { 'java/sql/Connection',  'java/lang/Object' }
stack: { 'java/lang/Object' }
Bytecode:
0000000: bb00 0359 b700 043a 052b b900 0701 0012
0000010: 08b9 0009 0200 c000 0a3a 0619 06b6 000b
0000020: 3a07 2bb9 0007 0100 b900 2801 0012 29b9
0000030: 002a 0200 c000 2b3a 082b 122c b900 0e02
0000040: 00b8 002d 3609 1905 bb00 2e59 b700 2f12
0000050: 30b6 0031 1509 b600 32b6 0033 b600 1cbb
0000060: 0034 592a b700 353a 0a19 0a19 06b6 0036
0000070: b600 3719 0a19 06b6 0038 b600 392b b900
0000080: 3a01 0012 3ba4 001b 2c12 3db9 003e 0200
0000090: 1905 123f 1240 b600 4119 052c b600 42b1
00000a0: 1509 ab00 0000 0a54 0000 0003 0000 0001
00000b0: 0000 0022 0000 0015 0000 029f 0000 0020
00000c0: 0000 0678 2a2b 190a 2db7 00cb 3a0a bb00
00000d0: 5259 190a b600 53b7 0054 3a0b 190a 190b
00000e0: b600 55b6 0056 190a 190a b600 5319 0ab8
00000f0: 00cc 105c b600 5704 60b6 0058 b600 5912
0000100: 053a 0c19 0ab6 005a c600 0d19 0ab6 005a
0000110: b600 553a 0c01 3a0d 013a 0e11 0400 bc08
0000120: 3a0f 190c 102e b600 5b02 9f00 2a19 0abb
0000130: 002e 59b7 002f 190c 0319 0c10 2eb6 005b
0000140: b600 5cb6 0031 125d b600 31b6 0033 b600
0000150: 5ea7 001c 190a bb00 2e59 b700 2f19 0cb6
0000160: 0031 125d b600 31b6 0033 b600 5e19 0ab6
0000170: 005f 9901 1bbb 0060 59bb 0061 5919 0ab6
0000180: 0062 b700 63b7 0064 3a0d bb00 6559 190a
0000190: b600 5ab7 0066 3a0e 190d bb00 6759 190a
00001a0: b600 68b7 0069 b600 6a19 0e19 0fb6 006b
00001b0: 5936 109e 0010 190d 190f 0315 10b6 006c    00001c0: a7ff e919 0db6 006d 190e b600 6e19 0db6
00001d0: 006f a700 9d3a 1019 0519 10b6 00cd 1905
00001e0: bb00 2e59 b700 2f12 71b6 0031 190a b600
00001f0: 4fb6 0050 1272 b600 3119 0ab6 0068 b600
0000200: 3112 73b6 0031 1910 b600 74b6 0031 b600
0000210: 33bb 002e 59b7 002f 1271 b600 3119 0ab6
0000220: 004f b600 5012 72b6 0031 190a b600 68b6    0000230: 0031 1273 b600 3119 10b6 0074 b600 31b6    0000240: 0033 b600 4119 052c b600 4219 0db6 006d
0000250: 190e b600 6e19 0db6 006f b13a 1119 0db6
0000260: 006d 190e b600 6e19 0db6 006f 1911 bf19
0000270: 0abb 0052 5919 0ab6 0062 b700 54b6 0075
0000280: 190a 190a b600 68b6 0076 a700 0d19 0a19
0000290: 0ab6 0068 b600 5e2a 190a 1907 2d19 0403
00002a0: b700 77a7 0853 3a0b 1905 190b b600 cd19
00002b0: 0519 0bb6 007e b600 7f19 052c b600 42a7
00002c0: 0837 3a0b 1905 190b b600 cd19 0519 0bb6
00002d0: 0025 1287 b600 4119 052c b600 42a7 0819
00002e0: 3a0b 1905 190b b600 cd19 0bb6 0088 128a
00002f0: a000 2719 05bb 002e 59b7 002f 190a b600
0000300: 86b6 0031 190b b600 8bb6 0031 b600 3312
0000310: 8cb6 0041 a700 2419 05bb 002e 59b7 002f
0000320: 190a b600 86b6 0031 190b b600 8bb6 0031
0000330: b600 3312 8db6 0041 1905 2cb6 0042 a707
0000340: b819 0a2b 128f 03b8 0090 b600 912b 12ce
0000350: b900 0e02 00b8 004d 3712 1612 0994 9900
0000360: 0a19 0a16 12b6 0039 2d19 0ab6 004f 190a
0000370: b600 92b6 0093 2db6 0094 5719 0a2d 1295
0000380: b600 96c7 0008 1205 a700 092d 1295 b600
0000390: 96b6 0097 190a 2d12 98b6 0096 b600 992d
00003a0: b600 9a19 0a19 0ab6 009b 129c 129d b800
00003b0: 9eb6 0099 190a b600 9b10 5cb6 0057 029f
00003c0: 001c 190a 190a b600 9b19 0ab6 009b 105c
00003d0: b600 5704 60b6 0058 b600 9919 0a12 0519
00003e0: 0ab6 009f b600 a099 000b 190a b600 9ba7
00003f0: 0008 190a b600 9fb6 00cf 1905 bb00 2e59
0000400: b700 2f12 a1b6 0031 190a b600 4fb6 0050
0000410: 12a2 b600 3119 0ab6 0092 b600 3212 a3b6
0000420: 0031 190a b600 9fb6 0031 12a4 b600 3119
0000430: 0ab6 009b b600 31b6 0033 b600 1c2d 190a
0000440: b600 4f19 0ab6 0092 b600 a53a 0d01 3a0e
0000450: 013a 0f12 0519 0ab6 009f b600 a09a 0229
0000460: 1104 00bc 083a 1019 0a19 0ab6 004f 12a6
0000470: 03b8 00a7 b600 a8bb 0052 59bb 002e 59b7
0000480: 002f 1908 b600 a9b6 0031 190a b600 aab6
0000490: 0031 b600 33b7 0054 3a14 bb00 ab59 bb00
00004a0: 6159 1914 b700 acb7 00ad 3a15 190d 1910
00004b0: b600 ae59 3611 9b00 1019 1519 1003 1511
00004c0: b600 afa7 ffe9 190d b600 b019 15b6 00b1
00004d0: a700 123a 1619 0db6 00b0 1915 b600 b119
00004e0: 16bf 013a 17bb 00b2 5919 14b7 00b3 3a17
00004f0: 1917 b600 b43a 1619 16b9 00b5 0100 9900
0000500: 9d19 16b9 00b6 0100 c000 673a 1819 1719
0000510: 18b6 00b7 3a0d 190a 190a b600 4f19 0ab6
0000520: 00d0 190a b600 92b8 00a7 b600 a8bb 0052
0000530: 59bb 002e 59b7 002f 1908 b600 a9b6 0031
0000540: 190a b600 aab6 0031 b600 33b7 0054 3a0f
0000550: bb00 ab59 bb00 6159 190f b700 acb7 00ad
0000560: 3a15 190d 1910 b600 ae59 3611 9b00 1019
0000570: 1519 1003 1511 b600 afa7 ffe9 190d b600
0000580: b019 15b6 00b1 a700 123a 1919 0db6 00b0
0000590: 1915 b600 b119 19bf a7ff 5f19 17b6 00b8
00005a0: 1914 b600 b999 00c9 1914 b600 7903 bd00
00005b0: 7ab8 007b b800 7ca7 00b7 3a18 1905 1918
00005c0: b600 cd19 05bb 002e 59b7 002f 1271 b600
00005d0: 3119 0ab6 004f b600 5012 bab6 0031 190a
00005e0: b600 d0b6 0031 1273 b600 3119 18b6 0074
00005f0: b600 31b6 0033 bb00 2e59 b700 2f12 71b6
0000600: 0031 190a b600 4fb6 0050 12ba b600 3119
0000610: 0ab6 00d0 b600 3112 73b6 0031 1918 b600
0000620: 74b6 0031 b600 33b6 0041 1905 2cb6 0042
0000630: 1917 b600 b819 14b6 00b9 9900 1219 14b6
0000640: 0079 03bd 007a b800 7bb8 007c b13a 1a19
0000650: 17b6 00b8 1914 b600 b999 0012 1914 b600
0000660: 7903 bd00 7ab8 007b b800 7c19 1abf bb00
0000670: 6559 190f b700 663a 0e19 0a19 0ab6 00d0
0000680: b600 99a7 0013 2d19 0ab6 004f 190a b600
0000690: 92b6 00a5 3a0e 2c12 bbbb 002e 59b7 002f
00006a0: 12bc b600 3119 0ab6 009b b600 31b6 0033
00006b0: b900 bd03 0019 0fc6 001a 190f b600 b999
00006c0: 0012 190f b600 7903 bd00 7ab8 007b b800
00006d0: 7cbb 00be 59bb 002e 59b7 002f 1908 b600
00006e0: a9b6 0031 190a b600 9bb6 0031 b600 33b7
00006f0: 00bf 3a10 1910 2c19 0eb6 00c0 a703 fa3a
0000700: 0d19 0519 0db6 00cd bb00 1d59 190d b600
0000710: 8819 0db6 008b b700 c1bf 190a 2b12 c209
0000720: b800 c3b8 00c4 b600 c519 0a2b 128f 03b8
0000730: 0090 b600 912d 190a b600 c6b6 00c7 190a
0000740: b600 92b6 0093 2db6 0094 5719 0a2d 1295
0000750: b600 96c7 0008 1205 a700 092d 1295 b600
0000760: 96b6 0097 190a 2d12 98b6 0096 b600 992d
0000770: b600 9a19 0a19 0ab6 009b 129c 129d b800
0000780: 9eb6 0099 190a b600 9b10 5cb6 0057 029f
0000790: 001c 190a 190a b600 9b19 0ab6 009b 105c
00007a0: b600 5704 60b6 0058 b600 9919 0a12 0519
00007b0: 0ab6 009f b600 a099 000b 190a b600 9ba7
00007c0: 0008 190a b600 9fb6 00cf 1905 bb00 2e59
00007d0: b700 2f12 a1b6 0031 190a b600 4fb6 0050
00007e0: 12a2 b600 3119 0ab6 0092 b600 3212 a3b6
00007f0: 0031 190a b600 9fb6 0031 12a4 b600 3119
0000800: 0ab6 009b b600 31b6 0033 b600 1c2d 190a
0000810: b600 c6b6 00c7 190a b600 92b6 00a5 3a0d
0000820: 013a 0e01 3a0f 1205 190a b600 9fb6 00a0
0000830: 9a02 2f11 0400 bc08 3a10 190a 190a b600
0000840: c6b6 00c7 12a6 03b8 00a7 b600 a8bb 0052
0000850: 59bb 002e 59b7 002f 1908 b600 a9b6 0031
0000860: 190a b600 aab6 0031 b600 33b7 0054 3a14
0000870: bb00 ab59 bb00 6159 1914 b700 acb7 00ad
0000880: 3a15 190d 1910 b600 ae59 3611 9b00 1019
0000890: 1519 1003 1511 b600 afa7 ffe9 190d b600
00008a0: b019 15b6 00b1 a700 123a 1b19 0db6 00b0
00008b0: 1915 b600 b119 1bbf 013a 17bb 00b2 5919
00008c0: 14b7 00b3 3a17 1917 b600 b43a 1619 16b9
00008d0: 00b5 0100 9900 a019 16b9 00b6 0100 c000
00008e0: 673a 1819 1719 18b6 00b7 3a0d 190a 190a
00008f0: b600 c6b6 00c7 190a b600 d019 0ab6 0092
0000900: b800 a7b6 00a8 bb00 5259 bb00 2e59 b700
0000910: 2f19 08b6 00a9 b600 3119 0ab6 00aa b600
0000920: 31b6 0033 b700 543a 0fbb 00ab 59bb 0061
0000930: 5919 0fb7 00ac b700 ad3a 1519 0d19 10b6
0000940: 00ae 5936 119b 0010 1915 1910 0315 11b6
0000950: 00af a7ff e919 0db6 00b0 1915 b600 b1a7
0000960: 0012 3a1c 190d b600 b019 15b6 00b1 191c
0000970: bfa7 ff5c 1917 b600 b819 14b6 00b9 9900
0000980: c919 14b6 0079 03bd 007a b800 7bb8 007c
0000990: a700 b73a 1819 0519 18b6 00cd 1905 bb00
00009a0: 2e59 b700 2f12 71b6 0031 190a b600 4fb6
00009b0: 0050 12ba b600 3119 0ab6 00d0 b600 3112
00009c0: 73b6 0031 1918 b600 74b6 0031 b600 33bb
00009d0: 002e 59b7 002f 1271 b600 3119 0ab6 00c6
00009e0: b600 c812 bab6 0031 190a b600 d0b6 0031
00009f0: 1273 b600 3119 18b6 0074 b600 31b6 0033
0000a00: b600 4119 052c b600 4219 17b6 00b8 1914
0000a10: b600 b999 0012 1914 b600 7903 bd00 7ab8
0000a20: 007b b800 7cb1 3a1d 1917 b600 b819 14b6
0000a30: 00b9 9900 1219 14b6 0079 03bd 007a b800
0000a40: 7bb8 007c 191d bfbb 0065 5919 0fb7 0066
0000a50: 3a0e 190a 190a b600 d0b6 0099 a700 162d
0000a60: 190a b600 c6b6 00c7 190a b600 92b6 00a5
0000a70: 3a0e 2c12 bbbb 002e 59b7 002f 12bc b600
0000a80: 3119 0ab6 009b b600 31b6 0033 b900 bd03
0000a90: 0019 0fc6 001a 190f b600 b999 0012 190f
0000aa0: b600 7903 bd00 7ab8 007b b800 7cbb 00be
0000ab0: 59bb 002e 59b7 002f 1908 b600 a9b6 0031
0000ac0: 190a b600 9bb6 0031 b600 33b7 00bf 3a10
0000ad0: 1910 2c19 0eb6 00c0 a700 1e3a 0d19 0519
0000ae0: 0db6 00cd bb00 1d59 190d b600 8819 0db6
0000af0: 008b b700 c1bf a700 613a 0b19 0519 0bb6
0000b00: 00cd 1905 bb00 2e59 b700 2f19 0ab6 0086
0000b10: b600 3119 0bb6 0025 b600 31b6 0033 128c
0000b20: b600 4119 052c b600 42a7 002d 3a0c 1905
0000b30: 190c b600 cd19 05bb 002e 59b7 002f 190a
0000b40: b600 86b6 0031 190c b600 25b6 0031 b600
0000b50: 3312 8cb6 0026 b1b1

Servlet jars

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>servlets.com</groupId>
            <artifactId>cos</artifactId>
            <version>05Nov2002</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>//1.2
        </dependency>
```